# How to deploy to aws elastic beanstalk with github actions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, github-actions

I'm currently trying to do an automated deployment through github actions. Below is my current workflow yaml file:

```
name: Deploy AWS
on: [workflow_dispatch]

    
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    
    - name: 'Git: Checkout source code'
      uses: actions/checkout@v1

    - name: '.NET Core: Setup'
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: '3.0.*'
    
    - name: '.NET Core: Get dependencies'
      run: dotnet restore
    
    - name: '.NET Core: Build'
      run: dotnet build --configuration Debug --no-restore

    - name: 'AWS: Timestamp action'
      uses: gerred/actions/current-time@master
      id: current-time
      
    - name: 'AWS: String replace action'
      uses: frabert/replace-string-action@master
      id: format-time
      with:
        pattern: '[:\.]+'
        string: "${{ steps.current-time.outputs.time }}"
        replace-with: '-'
        flags: 'g'

    - name: 'AWS: Generate build archive'
      run: (cd ./project.Api/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.0 && zip -r "../../../../${{ steps.format-time.outputs.replaced }}.zip" . -x '*.git*')
    
    - name: 'AWS: Deploying build'
      uses: einaregilsson/beanstalk-deploy@v14
      with:
        aws_access_key: { my_access_key }
        aws_secret_key: { my_secret_key }            
        application_name: api_test
        environment_name: my-api-test
        version_label: "v${{ steps.format-time.outputs.replaced }}"
        region: ap-southeast-2
        deployment_package: "${{ steps.format-time.outputs.replaced }}.zip"
        
    - name: 'AWS: Deployment complete'
      run: echo Should be on EB now
```

The current elastic beanstalk environment is setup with a load balancer - which I think is the main issue being caused with the deployment failing. I haven't been able to find a solution on how to deploy to aws elastic beanstalk when the environment contains a load balancer. [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know you had already done this, but it will help needy one :-)
I'm new here so not able to write correctly in box, but yaml code starts from "name:dotnet.." till end ,indent yaml accordingly

```
name: dotnet -> s3 -> Elastic Beanstalk
on:
   workflow_dispatch

#Setting up some environment variables
env:    
  EB_PACKAGE_S3_BUCKET_NAME : "php-bucket"
  EB_APPLICATION_NAME       : "dotnet-app"
  EB_ENVIRONMENT_NAME       : "Dotnetapp-env"
  DEPLOY_PACKAGE_NAME       : "dotnet-app-${{ github.sha }}.zip"
  AWS_REGION_NAME           : "af-south-1"

jobs:
 build_and_create_Artifact:
 runs-on: ubuntu-latest
 steps:
  - name: Checkout repo
    uses: actions/checkout@v3

  - name: Setup .NET Core
    uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
    with:
      dotnet-version: 6.0.*

  - name: Install dependencies
    run: dotnet restore

  - name: Build
    run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore

  - name: Test
    run: dotnet test --no-restore --verbosity normal

  - name: Publish
    run: dotnet publish -c Release -o '${{ github.workspace }}/out'

  - name: Zip Package
    run: |
      cd ${{ github.workspace }}/out
      zip -r ${{ env.DEPLOY_PACKAGE_NAME }} *       

  - name: Upload a Build Artifact
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3.1.0
    with:

      name: .Net-artifact
      path: ${{ github.workspace }}/out/${{ env.DEPLOY_PACKAGE_NAME }}


    
  - name: "Configure AWS Credentials"
    uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
    with:
       aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}}
       aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
       aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION_NAME }}
       
  - name: "Copy artifact to S3"     
    run: aws s3 cp ${{ github.workspace }}/out/${{ env.DEPLOY_PACKAGE_NAME }} s3://${{ env.EB_PACKAGE_S3_BUCKET_NAME }}/
       
  - name: "Build Successful"
    run: echo "CD part completed successfully"
  
Deploy_Artifact:
 needs: build_and_create_Artifact
 runs-on: ubuntu-latest
 steps: 
  - name: "Configure AWS Credentials"
    uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
    with:
       aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}}
       aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
       aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION_NAME }}
     
  - name: 'AWS: Timestamp action'
    uses: gerred/actions/current-time@master
    id: current-time
  
  - name: 'AWS: String replace action'
    uses: frabert/replace-string-action@master
    id: format-time
    with:
     pattern: '[:\.]+'
     string: "${{ steps.current-time.outputs.time }}"
     replace-with: '-'
     flags: 'g'
           
  - name: "Create Elastic Beanstalk Application Version"
    run :  aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version --application-name ${{ env.EB_APPLICATION_NAME }} --version-label version@${{ github.sha }} --source-bundle S3Bucket=${{ env.EB_PACKAGE_S3_BUCKET_NAME }},S3Key=${{ env.DEPLOY_PACKAGE_NAME }}  --description SHA_of_app_is_${{ github.sha }}__Created_at__${{ steps.format-time.outputs.replaced }}
   
  - name: "Deploy Application Version"
    run: aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --environment-name ${{ env.EB_ENVIRONMENT_NAME }} --version-label "version@${{ github.sha }}"
   
  - name: "Successfully run CD pipeline"
    run: echo "CD part completed successfully"
```

Comment: Please add some markdown to your answer -- e.g. there should probably be a quoted code block starting at `#Setting up some...`.